# Datetime field using Rails on Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I'm using Rails to make a scheduling app with Postgres. I have a model Shift with two timedate columns, start_at and end_at. The migration to create it follows:

```
class CreateShifts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shifts do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :schedule
      t.datetime :start_at
      t.datetime :end_at
      t.string :position
      t.string :notes

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :shifts, :user_id
    add_index :shifts, :schedule_id
  end
end
```

When I try to create a record I get the following error 500 output:

```
GError: ERROR:  column "end_at" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type time without time zone at character 132
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
: INSERT INTO "shifts" ("created_at", "end_at", "notes", "position", "schedule_id", "start_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"
```

I am creating a valid DateTime object before the DB save, because I've used the logger to display it and it is correct. The params look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qornHMTAdikZJP/sByPIg//fFuYHHAQH3M/0R9XnP+o=",
 "shift"=>{"user_id"=>"1",
 "start_at(1i)"=>"2011",
 "start_at(2i)"=>"11",
 "start_at(3i)"=>"14",
 "start_at(4i)"=>"00",
 "start_at(5i)"=>"01",
 "end_at(1i)"=>"2011",
 "end_at(2i)"=>"11",
 "end_at(3i)"=>"14",
 "end_at(4i)"=>"00",
 "end_at(5i)"=>"02",
 "position"=>"",
 "notes"=>""},
 "schedule_id"=>"1"}
```

However, I can create a record via console by setting both fields to Time.now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:
Your `$2` in the `INSERT` statement is of type `time` instead of type `timestamp` (datetime)

> INSERT INTO "shifts"
>
> ("created_at", "**end_at**", "notes", "position", "schedule_id", "start_at", "updated_at", "user_id")
>
> VALUES ($1, **$2**, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"

Emphasis mine.
You must be mixing up parameters, `$2` is obviously not the one you display at the end of your posting. Or you inadvertently cast it to time before assigning. The part where you assign `$2` is not visible in the question, that is where the problem occurs, most likely.

Maybe some kind of typo like in your question where you mention `timedate` instead of `datetime`?

Comment: Actually I just needed to restart Thin. Even in dev mode, a migration to change the col from `time` to `datetime` hadn't taken effect, so it was trying to save a `time` to the field.

Comment: Same problem here - I just had to restart rails server - not sure why you accepted Erwin's answer - the answer seems to be your comment to restart your server.